# Neovim not showing correct background color

Tags: vimrc, neovim, terminal, linux-arch

I'm running neovim from a uxterm on arch linux with the solarized color scheme.

The issue is that on scrolling only the characters which are non-whitespace are displaying the correct background. [image: error screen]

This fixes itself on any redraw of the screen - resizing, etc. However scrolling doesn't fix it (I actually produced this image by getting it to display correctly and the scrolled up).

Another issue is that when I close vim the bash terminal's background is white apart from where text is. This issue resolves itself when the background is redrawn - eg switching workspaces in i3.

My `.vimrc`
    " Plugins will be downloaded under the specified directory.
    call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

```
" Declare the list of plugins.

" List ends here. Plugins become visible to Vim after this call.
call plug#end()

syntax on

set noerrorbells
set novisualbell
set t_vb=
set tm=500

set ai
set smartindent

set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4

if (has("nvim"))
  "For Neovim 0.1.3 and 0.1.4 < https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/2198 >
  let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1
endif

"For Neovim > 0.1.5 and Vim > patch 7.4.1799 < https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/61be73bb0f965a895bfb064ea3e55476ac175162 >
"Based on Vim patch 7.4.1770 (`guicolors` option) < https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/8a633e3427b47286869aa4b96f2bfc1fe65b25cd >
" < https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Following-HEAD#20160511 >
if (has("termguicolors"))
  set termguicolors
endif

set background=dark
colorscheme onedark
```

And my `.bashrc`

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export PATH=$PATH:~/go/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/go-1.9/bin
export GOPATH=~/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin

export TERM=xterm-256color

# Add colors to Terminal
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
source /usr/share/nvm/init-nvm.sh

alias vim=nvim

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin
```

Comment: what terminal is this?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt it is just a standard bash terminal

Comment: I believe @ChristianBrabandt was asking which terminal emulator you are using (and, arguably, which terminal standard it’s emulating). For example, I use Terminal.app on macOS and Gnome terminal on Ubuntu, both of which are set to emulate an xterm-256color.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble how would I find that out?

Comment: Depends on the OS, terminal, etc. Google might help, but so would the terminal settings screen and the sequence of steps you take to launch such a terminal.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I apparently am using `uxterm`, I am on Arch linux.

Comment: Well, try a different terminal first. I believe neovim had some problems with the BCE (background color erase) setting of terminals, but this should have been fixed (see [PR 8806](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/8806)). So might try with current master version of Neovim plus a different terminal emulator. If the problem persists in uxterm, you should most likely open an issue with the Neovim devs

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt so it seems that the problem is with the interaction of neovim with xterm rather than bash. No issues using termite.

Comment: @Cjen1 As Christian mentioned, please try the latest prerelease. https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases